# Using an Array & Range-Based For Loop to replace some basic lines of code

Tags: c++, class, object, variables, juce

I am using JUCE/C++. I have two classes that interact with each other as follows.

The first class "LabeledSlider" is used to create a rotary knob with a label on it:

```
class LabeledSlider : public GroupComponent

{
public:
    LabeledSlider(const String& name)
    {
        setText(name);
        setTextLabelPosition(Justification::centredTop);
        addAndMakeVisible(slider);
    }

    void resized() override
    {
        slider.setBounds(getLocalBounds().reduced(10));
    }

    Slider slider
    {
        Slider::RotaryHorizontalVerticalDrag, Slider::TextBoxBelow
    };


};
```

The second class, LabeledGroup is meant to be where objects of LabeledSliders are defined, made visible, and organized via FlexBox. This is to allow groupings of knobs:

```
class LabeledGroup : public GroupComponent

{
public:
    LabeledGroup(const String& name)
    {
        setText(name);
        setTextLabelPosition(Justification::centredTop);


        addAndMakeVisible(dummy1);
        addAndMakeVisible(dummy2);
        addAndMakeVisible(dummy3);
        addAndMakeVisible(dummy4);

    }

    void resized() override
    {
        //setBounds(getLocalBounds().reduced(10));

        FlexBox knobBox1;
        knobBox1.flexWrap = FlexBox::Wrap::wrap;
        knobBox1.justifyContent = FlexBox::JustifyContent::flexStart;
        knobBox1.alignContent = FlexBox::AlignContent::flexStart;

        Array<LabeledSlider*> knobs1;
        knobs1.add(&dummy1, &dummy2, &dummy3, &dummy4);

        for (auto *k : knobs1)
            knobBox1.items.add(FlexItem(*k).withMinHeight(80.0f).withMinWidth(80.0f).withFlex(1));

        FlexBox fb1;
        fb1.flexDirection = FlexBox::Direction::column;
        fb1.items.add(FlexItem(knobBox1).withFlex(2.5));
        fb1.performLayout(getLocalBounds().toFloat());

    }


private:
    LabeledSlider dummy1{ "Dummy 1" };
    LabeledSlider dummy2{ "Dummy 2" };
    LabeledSlider dummy3{ "Dummy 3" };
    LabeledSlider dummy4{ "Dummy 4" };

};
```

I want to be able to replace the manually defined lists of LabeledSlider objects in with arrays and for loops. This way I can define the members of each array for each LabeledGroup object individually elsewhere in implementation.

Eg. To create a LabeledGroup object called "envelope" with knobs "Attack, Decay, Release, Sustain". And another LabeledGroup object called "distortion" with knobs "Drive, Level".

As a first step to doing this, I would like to implement some basic arrays in the LabeledGroup class I already have for testing.

At its simplest, I would like to replace the lines:

```
addAndMakeVisible(dummy1);
addAndMakeVisible(dummy2);
addAndMakeVisible(dummy3);
addAndMakeVisible(dummy4);
```

with:

```
LabeledSlider group1string[] = { "dummy1", "dummy2", "dummy3", "dummy4" };
        for (LabeledSlider& i : group1string)
        {
            addAndMakeVisible(i);
        }
```

There is no error from doing so. But the knobs no longer show up when I build using this replacement. So it is clearly not functioning. Should that for loop replicate the exact four lines that are already there? If not, what am I doing wrong in the loop?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a vector of LabeledSlider, not four individual variables.

Comment: Please show the definition of `addAndMakeVisible()` - my first guess is that the lifetime of the argument makes a difference, and you have a dangling reference bug.

Comment: That's a built in Juce function described here: https://docs.juce.com/master/classComponent.html#a909c90277e8e95db68001a94e06b83bc

Comment: Mat whether I use a Vector or an Array, either way the same function must be performed to replace these lines. And if it's not working with an Array, I don't see how it will work with a Vector any different in this at least early example. But yeah, perhaps Vector is better long term if I can make it work.

Comment: Shouldn't you write { { "dummy1"}, {"dummy2"}, {"dummy3"}, {"dummy4"}} ?

Answer (score 1):

Your first try does not work because `group1string`, which contains and owns your `LabeledSlider`s, is local to the constructor and is destroyed at its end. You want to still store them in a member variable so that your object owns them.

Replace the member variables with:

```
private:
    std::vector<LabeledSlider> _sliders;
```

... and then the initialization looks like:

```
for(std::string const &name : {"dummy1", "dummy2", "dummy3", "dummy4"})
    addAndMakeVisible(_sliders.emplace_back(name));
```

... and that usage in `resize()` becomes:

```
for(LabeledSlider &slider : _sliders)
    knobs1.add(&slider);
```

(Not tested for lack of a MCVE)

Comment: Well I tried that but it just gave an error message: https://i.postimg.cc/tTk3zHB9/error_3.png

Comment: @mike you have an extra `LabeledGroup` that tries to declare a variable.